# How to represent the max power possible

Tags: algorithm, math

Kind of a math question, but very programming related. Doing some Big-O problems and I have an algorithm where a for loop will run n times, where k = input size, n = max power of 4 where `(k)/(4^n) >= 1`. How can I represent ***max power of 4*** where `(k)/(4^n) >= 1` in one mathematic statement?

Comment: As you say, this is really a [math.se] question. I agree that it's programming *related*, but that isn't sufficient to make it a *programming question*. That said, once you've established the expression you wish to evaluate, asking "how do I calculate `expression` using {some language/library}", **that's** a programming question, so do come back and ask that here if you need to :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
floor ( (log k)/(log 4) ).
```

Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematic statement: `[log_4(k)]`

Code: `floor( log(k) / log(4) )`

Answer (score 0):

Taking (k)/(4^n) >= 1, multiply both sides by 4^n to get k >= 4^n, and then take the log base 4 (log_4) of both sides to get log_4 k >= n, or n <= log_4 k. (Equivalently, take log of both sides and get log k >= log(4^n), then note log(4^n) = n log(4), and divide to get (log k)/(log 4) >= n). Choose the largest integer n satisfying this inequality, which is floor(log_4 k).

Answer (score 0):

log base 4 of k?  Can take the floor if you only care about integer n.